# Estimating probabilities with a probability as an independent variable

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

I'm having trouble figuring out if I should be using a logistic regression model, a linear regression model, or something else for a problem I'm working on.
I'm trying to estimate the probability of customer conversion (I have both number of trials and conversions) over a given period by the previous periods observed customer conversion rate and some other non-probability factors.

Linear regression seems unnatural because the dependent variable is bound between 0 and 1. I've got decent results here, but the residuals look a bit strange bc the true value is bound.
Where as with logistic regression, I'm unsure of the validity of using a probability as a predictor (and I'm getting horrible results when I try).

Any idea which approach makes most sense to try? In general, how should I think of estimating probabilities with probabilities?

Edit: More info. The general idea is conversion rate ~ prev conversion rate, price, potentially day of the week. The goal is to build an interpretive model to gauge the relationship between price and conversion rate. With a linear model just conversion rate ~ prev conversion rate explains most of the variance seen in conversion rate, which is unsurprising. Prev conversion rate speaks to the strength of the product in similar market conditions. When I run a logistic regression model using previous conversion rate as the only predictor, the deviance is massive, larger than the null deviance. I am working with aggregate data for each product in each period.

Comment: Why would you think there is any problem with using probability (really a proportion) as a predictor? What do you mean by "horrible results"? is it just that the results don't agree with theory/what you hope to see? Do you have data on individual trials or just in aggregate at each period? What do your models look like (i.e., what variables or on the left and right side)? Is the goal to build a predictive model, an interpretable model, or a model for inference?

Comment: @Noah I appreciate the thorough questions. See my edit above. Hope you have some insight.